# How to redirect to a single URI after Laravel 5 Auth?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What would be the best way to redirect to one constant URI after a successful Laravel 5 Authentication instead of redirecting to the indended URI?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are authenticating inside of your own controller you can do something like

`return Redirect::route('routealiashere');`

or

`return Redirect::url('path/to/route/here')`;

after verifying the credentials.

Comment: Okay, it seems like I should create my own controller and then override the redirect with a static path.

Comment: Correct, that is what I would do.

Comment: You don't have to create another controller. Laravel already ships with `AuthController`, that uses `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. There you can find `postLogin` method that you can easily overwrite in `AuthController` and replace intended redirect with your own static.

Comment: @max.lanin, Thanks.  I've overridden the `postLogin` method from `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` and it works nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
return redirect()->intended('user');
```